# Using subset on factor level does not work

Tags: r

I have a very simple problem and somehow I cannot solve it, despite two hours of trying to do so. Short of sending you the data, I have to explain my problem with words and very little code.

I have a dataframe (`elecData`) with several variables and a factor (`Partido`). All I want to do is to create a new dataframe selecting one factor level (`Podemos`), so that I have a dataframe in which only rows containing `Podemos` as a factor of `Partido` are present. The code I use is the following:

`PodemosSort=subset(elecData, subset=elecData$Partido=="Podemos")`

For some reason, the new dataframe does not select only the intended level (`Podemos`), but all levels of the factor. Moreover, I have used the subset function on a simple dataframe I made up to see if it works and it did. Why is it not working in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try ``PodemosSort=subset(elecData, Partido=="Podemos")``

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Are you sure there are rows with different levels? What does `table(PodemosSort$Partido)` return? You need to use `droplevels()` to remove levels from factors. Factors "remember" what's not there when subsetting by default.

Comment: It returns 260 cases for Podemos, 0 for all other levels. When I put levels(Podemos), it gives me all the variable names, however. OMG, I cannot believe this took me two hours. I used levels() to check if what I wanted it to do had worked.

Comment: Look at ``table(elecData$Partido)`` That should tell you how many observations have each value of the factor.

Comment: On a perphas related note, if I may, I encountered a perhaps similar problem with something else, so I am putting it here. I also wanted to apply:    PodemosSort1=PodemosSort[-which(PodemosSort$votePerc2015==0),] to eject values with 0. Previously, I renamed 3 levels and gave them the same name (Podemos). Now, when I apply the above function, nothing (that I can see) happens. Is this problem related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:4, B = factor(c("AA","BB","BB","AA"), levels = c( AA","BB")))
df
#   A  B
# 1 1 AA
# 2 2 BB
# 3 3 BB
# 4 4 AA
```

Check class of columns

```
sapply(df,class)
#        A         B 
# "integer"  "factor"
```

Levels of factor column `"B"`

```
 levels(df$B)   
 # [1] "AA" "BB"
```

Rows with Level `"BB"`

```
df[df$B == "BB",]
# A  B
# 2 2 BB
# 3 3 BB
```

**Number of rows with level "AA", "BB" using `table()` function**

```
table(df$B)

#  AA BB 
#   2  2
```

**Using `subset()` function**

```
subset(df, df$B == "BB")  
#  A  B
# 2 2 BB
# 3 3 BB
```

To drop levels with frequency count 0, use `droplevels()` function. If at all any level exists with frequency 0.

```
levels(df$B) <- droplevels(df$B)
levels(df$B)
```